# How do i fetch and show multiple data with multiple query which is dynamically generated

Tags: laravel

I have inserted multiple machine ids( separated with , ) in a single cell which I got from a multi select dropdown, now i have all the machine ids but i want to fetch all the data related to those machines( stored in table name 'machines' )  and show the data in the same page for all the ids.

[Hear is the image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh0Tj.png)

```
public function ShowProducts(Request $Request){
        $ProductTitle = $Request->id;
        $MillDetails = DB::table('plants')->where('PlantName',"=",$ProductTitle)->first();
        $Plants = DB::table('plants')->where('status',"=",'Active')->get();
        $AvailableMachines = $MillDetails->Machines;
        return $riun = explode(',',$AvailableMachines);
      //  return view('Site.mill',compact('MillDetails','Plants'));
    }
```

now I need help with fetching and showing the all the machines and related data to it.

well I am new to Laravel so any help will be really appreciated

Comment: have you created models ?

Comment: @DineshParmar yes sir i have for machines table i have created model with name machine and for plants the model name is plant

Comment: can you modify your Machines column values 2,4 to ["2","4"] ?

Comment: `$riun = explode(',',$AvailableMachines); $machines = Machine::whereIn('id', $riun)->get();`. You should also consider normalising your data by e.g. creating a many to many relationship between  machines and plants and using [eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$MillDetails = DB::table('plants')->where('PlantName',"=",$ProductTitle)->first();
```

Extract machine ids from MillDetails and you can directly use in Machine model.

```
$machines = Machine::whereIn('id',explode(',',$MillDetails->machine_ids))->get(); // use Model and column name as per yours
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make function like this way. it will give you your disered output.
add this code in your plant model file `Plant.php`

```
public function getMachinesAttribute()
{
    $machines= explode(',',$this->machines);
    return Machine::find($machines); //here Machine is your App\Models\Machine
}
```

you can now use it like this way

```
 $MillDetails = Plant::where('PlantName',"=",$ProductTitle)->first(); //here Plant is your App\Models\Plant
 $MillDetails->Machines;
```

may this will help you ...